# google assistant - index of playlist is always 0

Tags: node.js, media-player, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to make an app which includes a playlist.
when the user pauses or gives an other command i need to know where in the playlist it stopped.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < data.audiourl.length; i++) {
   
    mediaObjects.push({
      name: bookshelf_list[bookshelf_id].title,
      description: "test",
      url: data.audiourl[i].uri,
    });
  }

  conv.add(
    new Media({
      firstMediaObjectIndex: 0,
      mediaObjects,
      mediaType: "AUDIO",
      optionalMediaControls: ["PAUSED", "STOPPED"],
      startOffset: "0s",
    })
  );
```

conv.request.context.media.index should take care of this but it's always '0'.
is this a know bug and does anyone know a workaround?

conv.request.context.media.progress does work but only for the current file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKxGj.png)

Answer (score 0):

names of every file in the playlist needs to be different fixed it by adding a number to the end of every name

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.audiourl.length; i++) {
  mediaObjects.push({
    name: bookshelf_list[bookshelf_id].title + i.toString(),
    description: "test",
    url: data.audiourl[i].uri,
  });
}

conv.add(
  new Media({
    firstMediaObjectIndex: 0,
    mediaObjects,
    mediaType: "AUDIO",
    optionalMediaControls: ["PAUSED", "STOPPED"],
    startOffset: "0s",
  })
};
```